# Delete all text strings in all cells for a column B if it matches the text string in any of the cells in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in Excel, all cells contain text strings.  Column A contains 8000 cells,  Column B contains 3000 cells.  I need to check each cell in Column B to see if it contains the string in cell A1.  If it does, I need to delete that text, leaving the rest of the string in tact.  Then I need to do the same thing for cell A2, A3, and so on, all the way to cell A8000.  This would take forever to do manually and I know it should be easy for a VBA programmer, but I'm a total rookie and struggle on where to begin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simple way using BULK replace

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lRow
            .Columns(2).Replace What:=.Range("A" & i).Value, _
                                Replacement:="", _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                SearchFormat:=False, _
                                ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. I think we are synchronous! You and I are posting identical answers at the same time all over the place!

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth and everyone else, this is great!  One problem, though, this routine replaces the matching text strings in Column B with a space.  I need the string to just disappear completely, with no space in its place.  How do we avoid having that extra space?

Comment: Oops...  I figured out what I was doing wrong, it works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster way than Wolf5370 suggests. You can loop through all cells in Column A and do a replace on their found values in Column B.

Something like this should get you started.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Replace()

Dim wks as Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheet("Shee1") 'change to suit your needs

With wks

   Dim rngLook as Range, cel as Range
   Set rngLook = Intersect(.UsedRange,.UsedRange.Offset(1),.COlumns(1))

   For each cel in RngLook
      .Columns(2).Replace cel.Value, "", xlPart
   Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sigh... +1 for posting at the same time... Again! :) BTW, you are missing a DOT before `Columns(2)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Originally I thought a sort (each column) and a walk down the columns (master/transaction style). However, then I notice you are talking substrings, so sort order will not help.
The only way to do this is to nest one loop in another and check all 8000 cells 3000 times.

```
dim c1 as integer, c2 as integer

for c2=1 to 3000

for c1=1 to 8000

cells(c1,1).value = Replace(cells(c1,1).value, cells(c2,2).value, "")

next c2

next c1
```

Note this is hand crafted off the top of my head (so typos etc expected). Basically it is looping through all those times I mentioned, each time it is replacing the string - you could do it by copying cells(c1,1) to a variable doing the replace and seeing if it changes before writing back - test it over a few cycles and see which is faster.

EDIT: Fixed a couple of typos (actually missed the word 'Value' off the second term)

PS: If cells are confusing you can use Range instead - replace `Cells(c1,1)` with `Range("A" &c1)` and `Cells(c2,2)` with `Range("B"&c2)`

Comment: I understand your approach but have no idea how to write the code.  I've tried generating the basic code using the macro recorder while I move around from one column and cell to another, search for the substrings and replace it with nothing, etc., but that's not working well.

Comment: while this may work, the nested loops is a very slow approach. See mine and @SiddharthRout's answers below. Also, I think its backward, I think you want `cells(c2,2).Value = Replace(cells(c2,2).Value,cells(c1,1).Value,"")`

Comment: Yes Scott (and Siddharth Rout) have better ways - been a fair while since I did anything serious with Excel VBA - thanks for the new knowledge there guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're limited to VBA or if adding a column would be acceptable: such as below:
Excel has a built in worksheet function called substitute which may meet your need (Depending on excel version)

[image]

Notice how in D3 TH is shown when in B3 its THIS and the IS is dropped.

EDIT
ah but now I see you you need to "loop" this.  I'll have to rethink my response.

Comment: Yes but he wants to compare every cell in column A to every cell in column B, not just the ones in the same row.

Comment: Sorry, guess we crossed posts (I delete it if you wish, but then your reply will look odd). btw I didn't vote anyone up or down (I use up sparingly and down almost never)

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA. Just fill down this formula in column C:

`=VLOOKUP($B1,A:A,1,0)`

Assuming your data starts in B1, fill this formula down to B3000.

Now, if the value in column B is found in column A, you will see the matching value in column C, else you will see `#N/A`.

Finally, sort columns B and column C by the value in column C, then delete the ones you don't want.

This should take all of 30 seconds.

I'm sure someone will come along who can post the VBA equivalent of the above.

Comment: But he wants to look for a substring, not the whole column value - and then remove the substrings where found.

Comment: I don't think this works, as user has to check if all unique column A values are anywhere inside the column B values. VLookup cannot do that.

Comment: @Wolf5370 Substring? Ugh, I think I'll just delete my answer.